# Radcheckboxlist selected from database

Tags: c#, telerik, checkboxlist

On page load RadCBList items appear. But when I press search button they disappar.

Code here(ascx):

```
<telerik:RadCheckBoxList Enabled="false" runat="server" ID="cblDurum" AutoPostBack="false" Direction="Vertical" CssClass="content">
    <Items>
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="PS" Value="0"  />
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="LC" Value="1"  />
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="GB" Value="2"  />
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="MINOR" Value="3"  />
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="TEST" Value="4"  />
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="OTHER" Value="5"  />
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="PRESERVATION" Value="6" />
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="BORESCOPE" Value="7" />
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="TESELLUM" Value="8" />
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="SEVK" Value="9"  />
        <telerik:ButtonListItem Text="RECEIVING TEST" Value="10" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadCheckBoxList>
```

Code here(cs):

```
var result = apuSrv.GetInfos(txtWO.Text);
DataTable dt = result.ToDataTable();
if (dt.Rows[0]["PS"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[0].Selected = true;
if (dt.Rows[0]["LC"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[1].Selected = true;
if (dt.Rows[0]["GB"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[2].Selected = true;
if (dt.Rows[0]["MINOR"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[3].Selected = true;
if (dt.Rows[0]["TEST"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[4].Selected = true;
if (dt.Rows[0]["OTHER"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[5].Selected = true;
if (dt.Rows[0]["PRESERVATION"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[6].Selected = true;
if (dt.Rows[0]["BORESCOPE"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[7].Selected = true;
if (dt.Rows[0]["INN"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[8].Selected = true;
if (dt.Rows[0]["OUT"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[9].Selected = true;
if (dt.Rows[0]["RECEIVING_TEST"].ToBoolean())
    cblDurum.Items[10].Selected = true;
```

I have true/false from db. I want that I read them and fill cblist with them. But when postback is completed, cblist shows empty.

Comment: Is this code in `Page_Load()` ? Do you have any error ?

Comment: Object.ToBoolean()

Comment: This code is in button_click. There is no error. Checkboxlist items are disappear.

Comment: Your issue is elsewhere, everything works great in a simple project. Try to isolate your issue. When you find how to reproduce this bug you will know how to fix it.

Comment: Check for `clbDurum.Visible` in your code behind. Let only the vital properties on `clbDurum` declaration ( runnat id ).

Comment: Everything here is Working. May you update your question with more information on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Your code is working except for the `Object.ToBoolean()`

Too mutch if for me, here is a quick fix:

```
foreach (ButtonListItem Item in cblDurum.Items)
{

    Item.Selected = (bool)dt.Rows[0][Item.Text];

    // OR With
    Item.Selected = ((DataRow)dt.Rows[0]).Field<bool>(Item.Text);

    // OR BY Item.Value
   int IntValue;
   if ( int.TryParse(Item.Value, out IntValue) )
       Item.Selected = (bool)dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[IntValue]
}
```

This will raise error if :

1. dt.Rows[0] When there is no row.
2. Field(Item.Text) if there is no Field named like Item.Text
3. If impossible cast from object to boolean

The best way by far would be to use the [Databinding](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/checkboxlist/data-binding/server-side-data-binding).

Comment: There is no item selected yet. Database send me true/false and if there is true then cblDurum.Items[0].Selected must be selected. But whole items and textes disappear.

Comment: There is no issue with the code you show in your question, it works. I understand your issue. But he code in the question is not the source of the issue. I have commented the question giving you a quick guide line to find where the behavior comes from.